# Why shouldn't I set http.WriteTimeout to 0 (none) in my Go server?

Tags: go, http, timeout

What are the consequences/dangers of setting `http.WriteTimeout` to 0 (none) in my Go server? Also, I am not using `http.TimeoutHandler`

My understanding is that `WriteTimeout` simply ends the connection for the client while continuing any long-running server processing. This seems confusing to the client, because the client doesn't know if their request actually completed or not.

I am using `http.ReadTimeout`. Sample config:

```golang
http.Server{
        Addr:              address,
        Handler:           handler,
        ReadTimeout:       25 * time.Second,
        WriteTimeout:      0 * time.Second,
        ReadHeaderTimeout: 5 * time.Second,
        IdleTimeout:       5 * time.Minute,
        MaxHeaderBytes:    1 << 18, // 0.25 MB (262144 bytes)
        BaseContext: func(l net.Listener) context.Context {
            return ctx
        },
```

Comment: "My understanding is that WriteTimeout simply ends the connection for the client while continuing any long-running server processing" [the documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Server) says "the maximum duration before timing out writes of the response".  That's distinct from processing time, which doesn't have a direct timeout.  "What are the consequences/dangers" uncooperative clients can keep the socket open indefinitely without reading from it, which will block the response writer.  Eventually that can lead to resource depletion for all the open sockets